# ABCpdf8 MSHTML Engine and SVG

Tags: c#, asp.net, svg, mshtml, abcpdf

I want to add an SVG image file that is specified in html in an img tag to my PDF using the MSHTML engine. The image appears properly in the browser using the same html. However, when I use AddImageHtml to add to the PDF, the SVG does not appear (it displays the broken image icon). If I switch to Gecko, the image appears as expected.

I would prefer to use MSHTML as the engine because the HTML content I have to work with was optimized for IE. Is there a setting or something that I am missing that would cause the IE9 MSHTML engine to not render a static SVG image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ABCpdf Component Comparison](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-8.htm) links the term "Embedded SVG" to a [ForGecko](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf9net/source/5-abcpdf/xhtmloptions/2-properties/2-forgecko.htm) only property.

Comment: Yes, the WebSuperGoo support confirmed that SVG is Gecko only. :(